# Getting EKS namespaces using boto3

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-eks

I have several accounts in aws, which i control daily. In some of them i have eks clusters. Usually, if i want to see the available namespaces in the cluster, i’m logging into the cluster and then run `kubectl get ns` from windows terminal.
How can i use this command with python?
(I’m using boto3 to write my query in aws, and trying to do everything within boto3 module)

I’ve already entered inside the cluster, but using describe_cluster i don’t have that info i’m looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can not get cluster resources with `boto3`. With additional libraries you can get k8s cluster resources with python. [`kubernetes`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), [`eks_token`](https://pypi.org/project/eks-token/) libraries can help you.

An example [usage](https://www.analogous.dev/blog/using-the-kubernetes-python-client-with-aws/)